# Javascript to add HTML error

Tags: javascript, html

I added this Javascript code to add some html to my footer (Want to have "Follow us on" on the left side of the Facebook icon)  -

```
document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML = "Follow Us";
```

For some reason it completely removed the footer. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Code seems ok. 
[image: Footer before adding code]
[image: Footer after adding code]

Any idea what is going wrong? (Want to use Javascript to add this HTML)

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the line.

Comment: this will remove everything and set it. try appending code.

appendChild() that is function.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me. Still same problem after adding the colon

Comment: @xkrlaix sorry dont understand

Comment: document.getElementById("footer").appendChild( Put your text or div or any container here )

Comment: @snack_overflow JavaScript inserts missing semicolons automatically ([ASI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)).

Comment: thank you but still does not seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're swaping the html inside the footer content to the string `Follow Us`. You have two options:

### Option 1 in Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML += "Follow Us";
```

### Option 2 in Jquery:

```
$('#footer').append('Follow Us');
```

Check if you're using the correct object `ID` too.

Comment: @java11 because it's a simple question that you can get an answer by just doing a simple research on google.

Comment: It may be a simple question but the problem is not simple.